# PHP-send an email at specific time

Tags: php

My system is for reservations, and I want to send a reminder email 15 minutes before without using cron on Linux/Unix/BSD boxen nor Scheduled Tasks on Windows because I'm using mac and the users' PCs will be windows.

So, what should I do?

Initially, I compared all date and time with the ones in the data base but still nothing arrived.

Thanks in advance.

---

I tried if the date&time now = the date&time in the DB send a conformation email.

and about the corn I have 2 things:

1- I'm using mac -as a programmer- and if I want to implement this function I'll have to use Scheduled Tasks on Windows which - as I think- will be need working on a windows environment.
and the system will be installed on a Microsoft PC.

2- I have not dealt with corns before, and I'm afraid it'll take time that  I don't have.

Comment: so, What have you tried?

Comment: What's the problem with using crons?

Comment: Users PC won't have anything to do with email sending, will they ?

Comment: You should use a cron.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use some kind of service or job to trigger the email to be send. Because php is self needs to know when to exec the code ("script").

Use CRON or Task Scheduler or build your own job / Service

Answer (score 0):

For Scheduling jobs on linux you can you at command. Here is example

```
at 12:32 -m -f /usr/local/bin/backup-script
```

Here is good manual for at linux.

http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/The_at_Command.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid cron job, then you have to depend on some hacky solution to trigger/call your "send email" code

like,

- depend on site users. If they are coming on regular intervals every minute, check on each reservation the upcoming reservation time and email to them.
- run a daemon process OR a function that keeps running for a specific period of time, say 24 hours, and check for upcoming reservations every minute or xyz time. You can put this process on sleep for a minute (or more) to check reservations on regular intervals.
- use 3rd party cronjob scripts or hosted cronjobs. like https://www.setcronjob.com/ (needs $ for this solution) or onlinecrontab.com

Comment: my php code didn't work with me. So I was thinking about using the third option therefor I created accounts on both of them but I didn't find any guide how to use it. And about the $ thing is their a trail or something I need this thing to work just for this week. one more question does it work on windows+mac platforms ? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I have not used the 3rd party cronjobs. Seems like, there are tons of free cronjob hosts where you can schedule your url to be called. Maybe you should ask your webhost (if you are using any 3rd party hosting) to help u setup cronjob becoz thats the legitimate solution. You can also use some opensource email sceduler solutions, like phplist. You can easily setup phplist and schedule the email by using its API. mailchimp is also a good & free(for 2000 subscribers of a mailinglist) service, actually its the best. i had a good experience with it.